# How to check the user already has 4 images in the array and don't let to continue to the next step in Node.js Express?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to set the limit of count on images. The point is that I've already set it in Mongoose but as far as images are getting uploaded to the cloud I think something should be added before the uploading and check first if the length of images array is less then 4. here is the code.

**Mongoose**

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: { type: String },
  email: { type: String },
  isVerified: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  picVersion: { type: String, default: '1531305955' },
  picId: { type: String, default: 'default.png' },
  images: {
    type:[{
      imgId: { type: String, default: '' },
      imgVersion: { type: String, default: '' }
    }],
    validate: [arrayLimit, 'You can upload only 4 images']
  },
  city: { type: String, default: '' },
});


function arrayLimit(val) {
  return val.length <= 4;
}
```

**controller**

```
 UploadImage(req, res) {

 // check if images array length is <== 4 and then let bellow function

    cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.body.image, async result => {
      await User.update(
        {
          _id: req.user._id
        },
        {
          $push: {
            images: {
              imgId: result.public_id,
              imgVersion: result.version
            }
          }
        }
      )
        .then(() =>
          res
            .status(HttpStatus.OK)
            .json({ message: 'Image uploaded successfully' })
        )
        .catch(err =>
          res
            .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            .json({ message: 'Error uploading image' })
        );
    });
  },
```

What should I add before the `cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.body.image, async result => {`
for checking it first?

Answer (score 0):

well you can actually alter the way you do your update mate..
I suggest you to use findOne() then use update your User after that, because when doing that you have more control over the update than just using update.. so here try like this

```
UploadImage(req, res) {
User.findOne({ _id: req.user._id })
.then((user) => {
    if (user) {
        if (user.images.type.length <= 4) {
            cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.body.image, async result => {
                user.image.type.push({ imgId: result.public_id, imgVersion: result.version });
                user.save()
                    .then(res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({ message: 'Image uploaded successfully' }))
                    .catch(); //use callback inside save() or use it like promise
            });

        }
    } else { res.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({ message: 'Error uploading image' }); }
})
.catch(err => res.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({ message: 'Error uploading image' }));
```

}

by doing it like this you can achieve what you are looking for .. cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the point is that I need to check it before Cloudinary.uploader not after that. Because if I use this way then the cloud will be crowded with lots of images.

Comment: oh ok in that case you can do as I have done but only when the req hit the endpoing, you can query user and do it the way I have done it..

Comment: I have edited it Check again please now you will find the way you want it

Comment: I will test it soon and tell you. Thanks one more time.

Comment: no problem If you find this was helpful and works make sure you mark the answer mate :)

Comment: 500 internal Error uploading image

Comment: console log it in your route to see where it breaks

Comment: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({ message: 'Error uploading image' either here or the last after catch.

Comment: change the message: 'error uploading image' to message:'error1' and message:'error2' and see where it breaks

Comment: It throws last one Error 2

Comment: problem is there query doesn't finish that's why

Comment: try to use User.findById({req.user._id}). and  are you sure that your req object is having the user id like this format req.user._id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186992/discussion-between-thewolf-and-artyom).